# How can I make Linux use super instead of ctrl as the main modifier key?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts

My issue is that I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as a modifier in my Vim mappings. I use <kbd>Alt</kbd> as a modifier in my TMUX mappings. And coming from the Mac, I've grown accustom to using <kbd>Command</kbd> (i.e. <kbd>Super</kbd>) as the modifier for general OS shortcuts.

I've seen several posts on remapping keys, and perhaps I don't understand what that means in Linux terms, but I'm **NOT** looking to press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (ex: New window) and have that send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to Linux. Doing this would mean my OS shortcuts would be in the same <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> namespace as my Vim mappings, which introduces collisions.

Is there a way to force Linux to respond to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>some command key</kbd> for all the built-in defaults that would otherwise expect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>some command key</kbd>?

In other words, can I force Linux to use <kbd>Super</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question right. Do you want `Super+key` to be the same as `Ctrl+key`? Doesn't that mean you're reassigning the `Super` to behave as `Ctrl` does? What will the difference be, though?

Comment: "Linux" doesn't have "built-in defaults". Are you asking how to make `Super` the modifier for your window manager operations, and if so what window manager are you using?

Comment: Those shortcuts are usually built-in into applications. Some may allow you to change them, but I would not count on it.

Comment: @icarus I'm on Linux Mint (cinnamon) 19.2. And yes, that's precisely what I'm asking.

Comment: @Janka In Mac OS I can apply custom keybindings to any applicant's menu commands. There is no such options in Linux?

Comment: From a google search, it appears that cinnamon is a very opinionated window manager and doesn't allow you to configure it much. Obviously you could edit the source and recompile it. I don't have anything useful to add.

Comment: Assuming by "OS shortcuts" you mean "those used in the window manager", you can also switch to a different window manager that is more configurable. Note that unlike MacOS, Linux has no concept of "OS shortcuts" - every application does whatever it likes. Though applications using a particular library exhibit similar behaviour (and there are several different of those library. Linux is a Bazaar, not a Cathedral). In particular, there's no equivalent to Cmd-C, Cmd-V etc.

Comment: @Nathan: MacOS has a style guide for applications, and also uses a common toolkit for building them. Linux is a functional anarchy. You have to specify which applications you want to change and we can look up an easy way to do that. Often this involves configuration per toolkit, sometimes configuration per application and sometimes you had to edit the source and recompile. So, there's certainly a way to do it but difficulty varies.

Comment: Thanks guys. I understand now that Linux doesn't really have a solution to the keyboard mapping problem that I have.

Comment: It sounds to me like we could take one or more of these comments and create an Answer to the question here ("no" is an acceptable answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since that you are using Cinnamon open `Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts` and change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to <kbd>Super</kbd>.

Do the same for the shortcuts of the apps that you want to change, sometimes there isn't an option so is not possible without recompiling the code.